# Golang readers: Why writing int64 numbers using bitwise operator <<

Tags: go

I have come across the following code when dealing with Go readers to limit the number of bytes read from a remote client when sending a file through multipart upload (e.g. in Postman).

```golang
r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, 32<<20+1024)
```

If I am not mistaken, the above notation should represent 33555456 bytes, or 33.555456 MB (32 * 2 ^ 20) + 1024. Or is this number not correct?

What I don't understand is:

- why did the author use it like this? Why using `20` and not some other number?
- why the author used the notation `+1024` at all? Why didn't he write 33 MB instead?
- would it be OK to write 33555456 directly as int64?

Comment: Yes, it will work if you write `33555456`, but then it won't be immediately clear that 32M + 1K is meant. As for why the particular limit is used, you'd better ask the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I am not mistaken, the above notation should represent 33555456 bytes, or 33.555456 MB (32 * 2 ^ 20) + 1024. Or is this number not correct?

Correct. You can trivially check it yourself.

```
fmt.Println(32<<20+1024)
```

> Why didn't he write 33 MB instead?

Because this number is not 33 MB. 33 * 1024 * 1024 = 34603008

> would it be OK to write 33555456 directly as int64?

Naturally. That's what it likely is reduced to during compilation anyway. This notation is likely easier to read, once you figure out the logic behind 32, 20 and 1024.

Ease of reading is why I almost always (when not using ruby) write constants like "50 MB" as `50 * 1024 * 1024` and "30 days" as `30 * 86400`, etc.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for your answer :)
Is there a reason why in << exactly number 20 is used?

Comment: Shifting by 20 places is the same as multiplying by 1024 twice...

Comment: Thanks @aMike, didn't know that! You guys rock.